# How can i add contrasted lines from a layer to another?

Tags: layers, contrast, data-merge

Hi i have this layer :

[image]

And this layer :

[image]

And what i want to do is add those black lines to the red layer but i dont want the white parts , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

When you put the pavement image in a new layer above the red background, I would try to do some smoothing first to make the colors more consistent. Additionally, your image is of very bad quality and you should try to use a [better image](http://www.fallingpixel.com/products/1348/mains/pavement4.jpg) of a similar pavement.

When you think the quality of your image is OK, convert it into gray or black/white by thresholding and you get something like this:

> [image]

Now got to the *Layer* window and choose *negative multiply* as mode and adjust the level of the mixture as you like it. Your result will something like this

> [image]

which is hopefully the result you wanted. Btw, when you want the edges to be black, you just have to invert the edge image:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Place the paving stones layer above the red layer and apply a layer blending mode to the stones. Experiment until you get the effect you're after.

When you select a layer, the blend mode is available in a drop down menu toward the top of the layers panel.

[image]

Comment: And is there a way to make white or black parts transparents on a layer ?

Comment: Blend modes will essentially achieve selective transparency for you. For instance, #ffffff will render as transparent when the blend mode is set to multiply. Play around and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Actually, I should amend that last statement: White does not become transparent in multiply mode, it just won't change underlying color.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Brick layer above the Red layer and choose and set the layer to Multiply